# Jquery, ajax and image not changing second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table with a list of products from a database.

In that list there is a column which shows a on/off image which can be clicked to change the value on or off.

That column shows this from the database:

```
if ($product_special == 1) { 
    $check_icon_special = "<img id='special_off_" . $product_id . "' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=changeSpecial(" . $product_id . ",'off'); src='../assets/admin/layout/img/check_on.png'/>"; 
}else{ 
    $check_icon_special = "<img id='special_on_" . $product_id . "' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=changeSpecial(" . $product_id . ",'on'); src='../assets/admin/layout/img/check_off.png'/>"; 
}
```

Onclick it then sends this to:

```
        type:"POST",
    url: "/admin/special_change.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: 'id=' + id + '&state=' + state,
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){         
        if (state == "on") {
            $('#special_on_' + id).attr('src','/assets/admin/layout/img/check_on.png');
        } else {
            $('#special_off_' + id).attr('src','/assets/admin/layout/img/check_off.png');
        }
    },
```

This works. The database is updated and the image is showing the on or off image.

However, without reloading the page I can not change the status again. I know the problem, because the changeSpecial onlclick event is not changed.

I'm no expert in Jquery. Was already happy I could achieve this. Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: Can you add the code that shows where you change the `$product_special` variable being changed and also the `state` variable being changed? Also, how are you firing the AJAX post?

Comment: So how are you pulling that data.  If the data is in the database and you change it in the database, you need to get that back and change it within javascript

Comment: $product_special is a value from the database.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the onclick. The first time I click, the image will change and the database is updated. 
However the onclick will still show the same value. So If I click again it will pass the same value. Then nothing happens, because it is already showing that value.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that your elements are being created on the fly and the javascript does not see your new elements.  It looks like you may have to look into `.on()`.  is your onClick only on your element? I would suggest writing that into your javascript rather than in-line on an element that you have to recreate every time you click.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I changed the onClick to:

```
onClick=changeSpecial(" . $product_id . ");
```

Then in special_change.php I changed the query to first check in the database for the current value.

Based ont that value I send back what the image should be, on or off.

Then in the ajax part I changed things like this:

```
        success: function(msg){         
        if (msg == "on") {
            $('#special_on_' + id).attr('src','../assets/admin/layout/img/check_on.png');
            $('#special_on_' + id).attr('id', 'special_off_' + id);
        } else {
            $('#special_off_' + id).attr('src','../assets/admin/layout/img/check_off.png');
            $('#special_off_' + id).attr('id', 'special_on_' + id);
        }
    },
```